# Crosscompiler Binary compatibility in C

Tags: c, shared-libraries, binary-compatibility

I need to verify something for which I have doubts. If a shared library ( .dll) is written in C, with the C99 standard and compiled under a compiler. Say MinGw. Then in my experience it is binary compatible and hence useable from any other compiler. Say MS Visual Studio. I say in my experience because I have tried it successfully more than once. But I need to verify if this is a rule.

And in addition I would like to ask if it is indeed so, then why libraries written completely in C, like openCV for example don't provide compiled binaries for every different OS? I know that the obvious reason would be to set all the compile-time parameters, but other than that there is none right?

EDIT: I am adding an additional question which I see as a logical extension to the original. Isn't this how one would go and create a closed source library? Since the option of giving source goes out of the window there, giving binaries is the only choice. And in that case providing binaries for as many architectures as possible is the desired result, with C being an obvious choice for having the best portability between systems and compilers. Right?

Comment: Very interesting question. Strangely enough I've never really given this any deep thought even though I was the Debugger Guy back in the early and mid-80's in the world of UN*X. Of course I was mostly using the symbol table as a guide, but there still can be questions of bit-packing in structs and pushing args on the stack. I'm guessing in that world most of the code is/was compiled with one version or another of either the manufacturer's compiler or GCC, so there was an inherent consistency, but that's not quite what you're asking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the specific case of C compilers (MSVC and GCC/MinGW) in the Windows world, you are correct in the assumption of binary compatibility. One can link a C interface DLL compiled by GCC to a program in Visual Studio. This is the way C99 projects like ffmpeg allow developers to write application wiht Visual Studio. One only needs to create the import library with lib.exe found in the Microsoft toolchain from the DLL. Or vice versa, using mingw.org's pexports or better, mingw-w64's gendef tool, one can create a GCC import lib for a MSVC produced DLL.

This handy interoperability breaks down when you enter the C++ interface world, where the ABI of MSVC and GCC is different and incompatible. It may work, it may not, no guarantees are made and no effort is (currently) being done in changing that. Also, debugging info is obviously different, until someone writes a debug information generator/writer in GCC that is compatible to MSVC's debugger (along with gdb support of course).

I don't think C99 specifically changes anything to function declarations or the way arguments are handled in symbol definitions, so there should be no problem here either.

Note that as Vijay said, there is still the architecture difference, so a x86 library can't be used when linking to an AMD64 library.

---

To also answer your additional question about closed source binaries and distributing a version for all available compilers/architectures.

This is exactly the way you would create a closed source binary. In addition to the import library, it is also very important to hide exports from the DLL, making the DLL itself useless for linking (if you don't want client code to use private functions in the library, see for example the output of `dumpbin /exports` on a MSOffice DLL, lots of hidden stuff there). You can achieve the same thing with GCC (I believe, never used or tried it) using things like `__attribute(hidden)` etc...

Some compiler specific points:

1. MSVC comes with four (well, actually only three remaining in newer versions) different runtime libraries through /MT, /MD, and /LD. On top of this, you would have to provide a build for each version of Visual Studio (including Service Packs) to assure compatibility. But that is closed source binary and Windows for you...
2. GCC does not have this problem; MinGW always links to msvcrt.dll provided by Windows (since Windows 98), equivalent with /MD (and maybe also a debug library equivalent with /MDd). But I there are two versions of MinGW (mingw.org and mingw-w64) which do not guarantee binary compatibility. THe latter is more complete as it provides 64-bit options as well as 32-bit, and provides a more complete header/library set (including a substantial part of DirectX and DDK).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, of course different architectures need recompiling with other compiler i guess. What do you mean by C++ interface? Isn't it the same in all compilers that you can call C code from an external library if you encase it in
    extern "C" {... } ?
My question also extends to how you would develop a closed source library. You would need to provide binaries only so C which has admittedly the best binary portability would be an obvious choice, right?

Comment: Lefteris: see my update, and yes, `extern "C" { ... }` is what you need to provide a C interface. A C++ interface can be made by compiling with g++, and leaving out that part, which lets name mangling kick in, which is one of the show stoppers for cross-compiler compatibility.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it was pretty detailed. As for name mangling I know, I got it in my face many times in the past unfortunately and this is what pushed me turn back to C for portability in a few of my projects.

Answer (score 4):

The general rule is that IF your OS/CPU combination has a standard ABI, and IF that ABI is powerful enough for your language, most compilers will follow that ABI and as a result will be binary compatible, allowing you to link libraries (shared or static) compiled with different compilers to programs compiled with other compilers just fine.

The problem is that most ABIs are fairly weak -- they're designed around low-level languages like C and FORTRAN and date back to the days before object oriented languages like C++.  So they tend to lack support for things like function overloading, user-defined operators, exceptions, global contructors and destructors, virtual functions, inheritance, and such that are needed by C++.

This lack was recognized when C++ was designed which is why C++ has `extern "C"` -- which causes the compiler to limit itself to the standard ABI for certain functions, while disabling all the extra C++ features that the ABIs generally don't support.

Answer (score 2):

A shared library or dll compiled to a particular architecture can be linked to applications compiled by other compilers that target the same architecture. (By architecture, I mean a processor/OS combination). But it is not practical for a library developer to compile against all possible architectures. Moreover, when a library is distributed in source form, users can build binaries optimized to their specific requirements.